# How to connect Glassfish to PostgreSQL replication server setup

Tags: postgresql, glassfish, replication, connection-pooling

I run a Glassfish app server (3.1.2) with a JDBC pool connecting to 1 DB instance.

Now I created a replication setup with a second DB node. I like to loadbalance the DB by allowing read access to the replication slave.

Can I do this by GF configuration or does my application implementation need to take care of this ?

Thanks for any light
Sven

Answer (score 1):

PgBouncer [PgBouncer Wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer) does this job.
You still connect to 1 DB IP (the pgbouncer instance) and it will handle the Postgres Side with 2 or more DB instances.